# Turtle drawing a hexagon and hexagon grid

Tags: python, python-turtle

**current code**

```py
#import the turtle modules  
import turtle 
  
#Start a work Screen 
ws=turtle.Screen() 
  
#Define a Turtle Instance 
geekyTurtle=turtle.Turtle() 
  
#executing loop 6 times for 6 sides 
for i in range(6): 
    
  #Move forward by 90 units  
  geekyTurtle.forward(90) 
    
  #Turn left the turtle by 300 degrees 
  geekyTurtle.left(300)
```

My goal is to make a hexagon grid pattern and I am failing to do it properly. My first issue is if you run the code you get a hexagon but the top is flat, I can't get it to get the pointy corners to get on top. Second I tried to make the grid and it failed and I am not sure why I am unable to copy the same hexagon and clone it next to the other. I will or should have a file of the image that I am going for below.

The output I am getting:
[image]

The output I am trying to get:
[image]

Comment: Ok I will, give me about 5 mins and you should see it here

Comment: To tilt the hexagon, just add a `geekyTurtle.right(30)` at the start. Also, `right(60)` is somewhat faster then `left(300)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is a problem that recursion could simplify in a fractal-like way.  Each side of the initial hexagon is itself a hexagon, and so forth, filling the available space:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

SIDE = 75  # pixels

def hexagon(side, depth):
    if depth > 0:
        for _ in range(6):
            turtle.forward(side)
            turtle.right(60)
            hexagon(side, depth - 1)
            turtle.left(120)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)  # because I have no patience

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.width(2)
turtle.sety(-SIDE)  # center hexagons on window
turtle.pendown()
turtle.left(30)  # optional, orient hexagons

hexagon(SIDE, depth=6)  # depth depends on coverage area

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Yo thank you so much I can now run my code against this to see what I could change on mine

Answer (score 2):

1. Before going into loop, turn 30 degrees.

`geekyTurtle.right(30)`

2. In order to have its clone beside, just put the turtle to the new place and draw the shape again:

   ```
   for i in range(6):
     geekyTurtle.forward(90)
     geekyTurtle.left(300)
   geekyTurtle.up()
   geekyTurtle.goto(90 * 3 ** .5, 0)
   geekyTurtle.down()
   for i in range(6):
     geekyTurtle.forward(90)
     geekyTurtle.left(300)
   ```

Put it in a loop to have it for more than two times

3. You can use the idea of `.up()` and `.goto(x, y)` and `.down()` to draw grids.